# Deduce function overload with uknown type at compile time

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compile-time

I stumbled across this when trying to clean up a temporary variable. It seemed interesting enough to discuss.

```
ArrayType m_ArrayOfThings;
INT32 m_BitfieldOfThings;

...


// Assume MyType has a ctor overload with argument ArrayType and another with int32.
const MyType my_obj( m_ArrayOfThings.IsEmpty() ? m_BitfieldOfThings : m_ArrayOfThings )
```

Here is a simplified example of my set-up. Something similar may be found in UE4's `FCollisionObjectQueryParams` constructors.

---

Compiling the above will result in `error C2446: no conversion from 'INT32' to 'ArrayType'`, since the type passed is unknown at compile-time.

```
auto temp = m_ArrayOfThings.IsEmpty() ? m_BitfieldOfThings : m_ArrayOfThings;
const MyType my_obj( temp );
```

This will also throw: `error C3536: 'temp': cannot be used before it is initialized`.

It's obvious one should convert either variables to have matching types, so the type is known at compile-time, however, I was wondering if there exist semantics, tricks/hacks, or new features *(c++17, etc.)* to solve this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move constructor invocation to the right:

```
auto const my_obj{m_ArrayOfThings.IsEmpty() ? MyType{m_BitfieldOfThings} : MyType{m_ArrayOfThings}};
```

With C++17 this snippet will work even if `MyType` is non-copyable / non-movable and will invoke only one constructor.

Comment: It seems the `list-initialization` is key here to avoid move/copies? Or does `auto` play a part in this as well?

Comment: @Nikita `auto` is for avoiding writing `MyType` for the third time. move/copies is avoided due to C++17 initialization semantics.